# Required/Mandatory fields in Wordpress Admin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, validation

looking for a solution for Wordpress Admin where fields such as Title, Excerpt, Category are required before being able to publish. Warning message or alert displaying what is missing because it is required. I have found old solutions that work for classic editor, but they do not work with the block editor, and ones that do work for block editor do not work for classic editor . Have not found anything out there that works for both. Looking to plug in some code in the functions.php file. Any help would be appreciated for a jr dev here in Wordpress.

This works for classic editor only

```
    /** ADD Validation for title */
    function force_post_title_init()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
function force_post_title()
{
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
    echo "
  jQuery('#publish').click(function(){
        var testervar = jQuery('[id^=\"titlediv\"]')
        .find('#title');
        if (testervar.val().length < 1)
        {
            jQuery('[id^=\"titlediv\"]').css('border', '2px solid red');
            alert('Post title is required');
            return false;
        }
    });
  ";
    echo "</script>\n";
}
add_action('admin_init', 'force_post_title_init');
add_action('edit_form_advanced', 'force_post_title');
add_action('edit_page_form', 'force_post_title');
```

This works on classic editor but on block editor just refreshes back to the same post in draft.

```
/**
 * Checks for empty post title, if empty sets the post status to draft
 *
 * @param $data
 * @param $postarr
 *
 * @return array
 */
function abc_check_post_title( $data, $postarr ) {
    if ( is_array( $data ) && 'publish' == $data['post_status'] && empty( $data['post_title'] ) ) {
        $data['post_status'] = 'draft';
        update_option( 'abc_post_error', 'empty_title' );
    }

    return $data;
}
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'abc_check_post_title', 10, 2 );

/**
 * If the post title was empty, do not show post published message
 */
add_filter( 'post_updated_messages', 'abc_remove_all_messages' );

function abc_remove_all_messages( $messages ) {
    if ( get_option( 'abc_post_error' ) ) {
        return array();
    } else {
        return $messages;
    }
}

/**
 * Show admin notice for empty post title
 */
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'abc_show_error' );
function abc_show_error() {
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if ( $screen->id != 'post' ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( ! get_option( 'abc_post_error' ) ) {
        return;
    }
    echo '<div class="error"><p>' . esc_html__( "You need to enter a Post Title in order to publish it.", "wse" ) . '</p></div>';
    delete_option( 'abc_post_error' );
}
```

Comment: I'm sure if you add the two solutions you've found in your question, you will find someone to combine them into one working for both here. Plz edit your question with code.

Comment: Good point, added

Comment: @devSoupGuy61 sorry for not being able to help for this specific situation right now, but wanted to mention a very handy plugin for similar situations used by lot of WP VIP clients called edit flow where you control the flow of content before it gets published with all restrictions and notifications etc, maybe it come handy for ideas https://wordpress.org/plugins/edit-flow/